# std::memcpy divisibility requirements?

Tags: c++, serialization, std, memcpy

It is specifically required/heavily-encouraged for memcpy to be used against objects that are evenly divisible by 8 bytes? I keep seeing this come up in various serialization and gamedev guides, but I cannot find any reference to it outside of that. I understand that having code that is evenly divisible allows for easy/quick error checking, but is there any requirement or heavily-encouraged precedence for aligning data in a such a way?

One such reference : https://gafferongames.com/post/serialization_strategies/

> To align a bitstream just work out your current bit index in the
>   stream and how many bits of padding are needed until the current bit
>   index divides evenly into 8, then insert that number of padding bits.

Official references for std::memcpy() : 
[cppreference.org](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html), [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: I would recommend against `memcpy`.  The `memcpy` function should only be used on classes or structs with only POD` types.  A high quality approach is to develop copy or move constructors that handle each data member.

Comment: I didnt find in "One such reference" mentioning that divisible by 8 thing, I didnt read it completely though. Can you quote the relevant part directly here?

Comment: The `memcpy` function is designed to work on the size of the minimal addressable unit, for example, `uint8_t`.  It may be optimized to work more effficiently with sizes compatible with the processor's word size.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, those exist for my Packet class. However, I do need to serialize the data in from a char*. As for lowest size, it is potentially irrelevant so long as it's larger than the uint8_t or word size (which itself is more of a performance issue than straight up crash/failing/etc). Is that correct?

Comment: Your question is asking about byte multiplicity, but the quote speaks only of bits. Do not confuse the two, a byte is usually 8 bits. Since `std::memcpy` only works in bytes, and since bytes are 8 bit on most systems, it makes sense that `std::memcpy` would require that data be multiple of 8 bits (multiples of 1 byte) on those systems.

Comment: I don't recommend using structs to exactly model a data format or packet.  A better method is *serialization*, or create an array of `uint8_t` and have your class read from and write to the array.

Comment: use `std::copy`.  It will call `memcpy()` for POD structs in modern stl versions.